# 'This' typescript is undefined

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, cloudboost

I'm quite new to ionic / angular / typescript and cloudboost, and I'm trying to make this all work together.

I've starded a new ionic project with the "super" starter theme.

I've managed to make work for the cloudboost logIn function, nevertheless I face some issues :

- I didn't succeed to use the user provider as it is using Http service and Cloudboost does not give access to an url, and the original return is an observable.
- I can't access `this` in the callback function of CBUser.logIn, it is undefined.
  I tried several way with the fat arrow, but didn't work, so at the moment, I managed with this workaround :

  var falseThis = this;

How can I make it more clean for typescript ?

Here is my login.ts file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ModalController, IonicPage, NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

import * as CB from 'cloudboost';
import { User } from '../../providers/providers';
import { MainPage } from '../pages';

import { ModalCguPage } from './modal-cgu';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})



export class LoginPage {
  // The account fields for the login form.
  // If you're using the username field with or without email, make
  // sure to add it to the type
  account: { username: string, password: string } = {
    username: 'defaultuser@defaultsite.co',
    password: '01231234'
  };

  // Our translated text strings
  private loginErrorString: string;
  private loginSuccessString: string;
  private redirectPageSuccess : any = MainPage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public user: User,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public translateService: TranslateService,
    public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    this.translateService.get('LOGIN_ERROR').subscribe((value) => {
      this.loginErrorString = value;
    })
    this.translateService.get('LOGIN_SUCCESS').subscribe((value) => {
      this.loginSuccessString = value;
    })



  }

  // Attempt to login in through our User service
  doLogin() {  
//  HERE : get back the main this to use it later
    var falseThis = this;

//  cloudboost login
    let CBUser = new CB.CloudUser();
    CBUser.set('username', this.account.username);
    CBUser.set('password', this.account.password);
    CBUser.logIn({
        success: function(user) {
            let toast = falseThis.toastCtrl.create({
              message: falseThis.loginSuccessString + ' ' + user.username,
              duration: 3000,
              position: 'top'
            });
            toast.present();

            falseThis.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
        }, error: function(error)  {
    //    error: function(error) {
            // Unable to log in
            let toast = falseThis.toastCtrl.create({
              message: falseThis.loginErrorString,
              duration: 3000,
              position: 'top'
            });
            toast.present();
        }

    });
  }
}
```

Below the original function included in the starter template :

```
// Attempt to login in through our User service
  doLogin() {
    this.user.login(this.account).subscribe((resp) => {
      this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
    }, (err) => {
      this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
      // Unable to log in
      let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: this.loginErrorString,
        duration: 3000,
        position: 'top'
      });
      toast.present();
    });
  }
```

If someone can clear things, I would really appreciate.
Thank you

---

EDIT WORKING SOLUTION :

in login.ts

```
// Attempt to login in through our User service
  doLogin() {
    this.user.login(this.account).then( (user:any) => {
        console.log('user displayed ');
        console.log(user.username);

    //  login successful
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: this.loginSuccessString + user.username,
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top'
        });
        toast.present();

        this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
    }).catch( err => {
    // Unable to log in
      let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: this.loginErrorString,
        duration: 3000,
        position: 'top'
      });
      toast.present();
    });
  }
```

in user.ts :

```
login(account: any) {
         let CBUser = new CB.CloudUser();
         CBUser.set('username', account.username);
         CBUser.set('password', account.password);
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
             CBUser.logIn({
                 success: (user) => {
                 //Login successful
                     resolve(user)
                 },
                 error: (error) => {
                     reject(error)
                 //Error in user login.
                 }
             });
         });
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't access this in the callback function of CBUser.logIn, it is
>   undefined. I tried several way with the fat arrow, but didn't work, so
>   at the moment, I managed with this workaround

I think Pace answered this question. This link helped me as I faced this issue [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

For CloudBoost callbacks use:

```
{
  success: (obj) => {
    //success
  },
  error: (err) => {
    //Error
  }
}
```

> I didn't succeed to use the user provider as it is using Http service
>   and Cloudboost does not give access to an url, and the original return
>   is an observable.

The user provider is just an example to kickstart with Http requests. To use the user provider with cloudboost I would suggest changing the login function to something like

```
login(account) {
let CBUser = new CB.CloudUser();
CBUser.set('username', account.username);
CBUser.set('password', account.password);
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  CBUser.logIn({
    success: (user) => {
      //Login successful
      resolve(user)
    },
    error: (error) => {
      reject(error)
      //Error in user login.
    }
  })
 })
}
```

and call the function with:

```
this.user.login(this.account).then( user => {
  //login successful
  this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
}).catch( err => {
  this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
  // Unable to log in
  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: this.loginErrorString,
    duration: 3000,
    position: 'top'
  });
  toast.present();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, everything seems to be fine.
Expect one thing, I modified the call function to add a welcome message on success like this : 

 
           this.user.login(this.account).then( user => {
    //  login successful
       let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
         message: this.loginSuccessString + ' ' + user.username,
         duration: 3000,
         position: 'top'
       });
       toast.present();

       this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
    }


But i get an error message : `Cannot find name 'user'.`

What is the issue ?

Comment: Sorry the error message is this one exactly : 
 
`Property 'username' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Comment: @axx
 I have not tested it, but as the type of user is a subclass of CloudObject you should be able to use `user.document.username` alternative is using the get() function `user.get('username')` like it is described in the [api reference](https://docs.cloudboost.io/#CloudObject-get)

Comment: I tried : `user.document.username`, but failed to at build : 

`Typescript Error
Property 'document' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Same for  `user.get('username')`
It provide 
`Typescript Error
Property 'get' does not exist on type '{}'.`

I tried changing the name of user, to be sure there is no conflict with the class name also but didn't work either.

Comment: So finaly to get the user.username, be sure to declare `(user:any)`
or `(user:CB.CloudUser)` and `import * as CB from 'cloudboost';` at the top of your file (only if you use CB.CloudUser)

`this.user.login(this.account).then( (user:any) => {
        console.log('user displayed ');
        console.log(user.username);

    //  login successful
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: this.loginSuccessString + user.username,
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top'
        });
        toast.present();

        this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The example is using arrow lambdas which changes the rules for what happens with `this`.  Check out [this article](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript) for details.

```
success: function(user) {
  //this not accessible
}

success: user => {
  //this is accessible
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I can access it now ! 
I was trying `success(user : any) => `, but it wasn't working

Thank you also for the link.